# How to suppress small elements in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have an LSTM network that outputs a decision via `tf.tanh`. Then I use a `tf.sign` to get the binary action of either 1, -1 or 0. However, I do not want the model to make a non zero action when output of `tf.tanh` is small, so I want to implement a threshold `T` before `tf.sign` so that only output larger than T or smaller than -T will be transformed to +1 and -1.

Example tensor output from `tf.tanh`:

```
logits = [0.6,0.4,-0.6,-0.4]
threshold = 0.5
```

Desired tensor output while preserving the gradient:

```
action = [1,0,-1,0]
```

It's sort of like a double side ReLU with a threshold, but I don't know how to do it inside tensorflow graph. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works for me. The code is pretty self-explanatory if you look at the variable names. Let me know if something is unclear.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def suppress_range(x, a, b):
    """Sets all the elements in the range [a, b) to 0"""
    assert (a < b), "a must be less than b"
    significant = tf.logical_or(x <= a, x > b)
    zero = tf.zeros_like(x)
    return tf.where(significant, x, zero)

def main():
    logits = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    output = tf.sign(suppress_range(logits, -0.5, 0.5))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        x = [[0.6, 0.4, -0.6, -0.4], [0.5, 0.1, -0.7, -0.2]]
        print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={logits: x}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```